# How to stop a discord bot from responding to itself - Return if statement does not work

Tags: python-3.7, discord.py

I am pretty new to Python, and I am coding a discord bot using discord.py rewrite, python 3.7. Here is the issue: my bot keeps responding to itself, generating an infinite flow of repeated messages. I have searched for solutions to my problem, and what I have encountered seemed to be functioning correctly for everybody else, but not for me. Here is my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await message.channel.send("hi")
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

I have tried replacing

```
if message.author == client.user:
        return
```

with

```
if message.author.bot == True:
    return
```

as it seemed to be an alternate solution. However, none of them worked. I am not sure what to do.

Comment: What are the repeated messages? Endless stream of "hi", the message you send before the check?

Comment: Yes, I send any message in the chat and the bot replies with an endless stream of "hi".

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry! For some odd reason I thought I had already tried putting the if statement on top. Thank you so much, it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was solved. For those wondering: I simply had to move the

```
if message.author == client.user:
    return
```

to the top of the function. My final code was this:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    await message.channel.send("hi")
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: or just
if message.author.bot
    return