# Python Discord bot message.content

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to make my Discord bot to respond automatically when someone sends a specific word, the issue is that the command only works if the word is the first thing written in the sentence though. I would want the bot to respond to the message even when the speciifc word is in the middle or anywhere in the sentence.

Is there anything I could change to make it work?

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    words = ['test']

    if message.content in words: 
        await message.channel.send("test1")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python the format is `if substring in string:`

So if you have a list of words you're looking for then you need to first iterate over that list of words then check if it is in the main string:

```py
for word in words:
    if word in message.content:
```

or, you can do a sneaky:

```py
if any(map(message.content.__contains__, words)):
```

Which will return true if any of the words in `words` is in the message content.

Comment: Hmm this kinda fixed the issue, I now can have the word anywhere where I want, but when I send the test word, the bot replies 5 times every like 10 seconds with the same word.

Comment: Are you making sure the bot is not responding to itself? I mean the word test is inside of test1 so it would answer itself. Try changing test1 to somwthing that doesn't have test and see if it still happens

Comment: No worries, for that, this post is useful: [How to stop a discord bot from responding to itself - Return if statement does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54962041/how-to-stop-a-discord-bot-from-responding-to-itself-return-if-statement-does-n)