# Python Discord Bot Message Copy But Changing Content For 2 or More Words

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

some days ago, I have opened a question about bot message.content [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69683332/python-discord-bot-message-content)

Now, I would want the bot to replace two words in the same text with replying only with one message.

So far I have this.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    words = ['test', 'winter']
    changes = ['nice', 'summer']

    for word in words:
        if word in message.content:
            await message.channel.send(f"{message.content.replace(word, changes[words.index(word)])}")

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

This is what the bot does:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zI2U.png)

For some reason, it only works for one of the words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending the message to the channel every time around the loop

don't call `message.channel.send` until after all the replacement loops are complete.

you may consider making all the changes within the loop and using a single `message.send` after that is complete

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    
    words = ['test', 'winter']
    changes = ['nice', 'summer']

    response_message = message.content
    for word in words:
        if word in message.content:
            response_message = f"{response_message.replace(word, changes[words.index(word)])}"  # in place update

    await message.channel.send(response_message)  # send this one after the replacement loop

    await client.process_commands(message)
```