# Im trying to make a event so that when someone makes a message it replys to it

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

So far like I said I'm trying to make a bot so that when someone makes a message it responds with `"Hello"` and so on but when I try to do that I found the bot responding to itself.

My code:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop a discord bot from responding to itself - Return if statement does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54962041/how-to-stop-a-discord-bot-from-responding-to-itself-return-if-statement-does-n)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to check whether the `message.author` is your `bot`.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user: # check if the author of message is your bot
        return

    # rest of your code
    
    await bot.process_commands(message) # to correctly process commands
```

You might also want to add `await bot.process_commands(message)` to make sure that your [commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=commands) will work if you decide to use them. [Check this link to see why do you have to use it](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html?highlight=on_message#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working)